# aws ecs-cli extra-user-data: flag provided but not defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm facing a strange problem trying to configure a AWS ECS cluster through ecs-cli.
To be specific, if I use the flag --extra-user-data it says: flag provided but not defined.

here's my command syntax:

```
ecs-cli up --capability-iam --keypair test --size 1 --instance-type t2.small --extra-user-data file://init-ec2 --launch-type EC2 --force --cluster test --region eu-west-1
```

Here's the exception:

> ERRO[0000] flag provided but not defined: -extra-user-data

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: ecs-cli version: ecs-cli version 1.8.0 (33b5630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--extra-user-data` was released in version [1.9.0](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/releases/tag/v1.9.0) of ecs-cli.  The error message you've provided appears to indicate that you're running a previous version.  Update to the latest version of ecs-cli and try again.